# The remake of The Blob in the 1980s -- was an explicit child death rare prior to the 80s?

Tags: content-rating

I remember seeing this movie where the Blob kills a child and thinking how unusual that was. Is it possible that indeed on-screen deaths of children was very rare prior to this time and may have resulted in a more restrictive rating?

Comment: Off the top of my head, there's a kid shot by gang members in Carpenter's *Assault on Precinct 13* (1976).

Comment: Let's see. the 1988 version is rated **18** and the 1958 version **X** (which did not feature such a scene). Basically these are horror films and rated accordingly.

Comment: @paulie_d: are u saying 1958 Blob was rated X -- it sure was not.

Comment: Doesn't seem implausible to me that it would be X rated at all.  According to IMDB it was given an X rating in the UK (later revised to a 12 rating, times change).  It may have been shocking in its time.

Comment: @iandotkeylly: there were no x-ratings or any ratings in 1958.

Comment: Let me rephrase that ... It's not implausible to me that the 1958 movie was considered a serious horror movie for adults only.  It was given the strongest rating used in the UK at the time.

Comment: @iandotkelly: the rating system in the usa happened after that, in 1968. i do not know if in practice kids were prevented from seeing certain movies by theatre managers or what. a movie i have wondered about was Cape Fear, if an unaccompanied 12 year old went to it if he would be admitted.; maybe kids were for any movie only allowed in matinees and any nighttime showing required parents. much has changed. i checked into a hotel alone before i was 16 in the mid 1970s-- today that would be impossible.

Comment: You're missing the point .... Paulie_D is using the ratings of the two movies to try to show that the child death isn't a big factor.  They were both considered horror movies in their day.

Comment: @releseabe The question in the title and in the body are not the same: can you edit it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it wasn't the first film:

There is quite a long article about the "[Death of a child](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/DeathOfAChild/LiveActionFilms)" trope. Let me bring just a few examples:

- *Cross of iron* (1977) **R** shows the death of child-soldiers
- *Assault on Precinct 13* (1976) **R** was quite famous for its brutality: In one of the scenes, the gang leader kills a little girl who was trying to buy ice creams from a truck
- **Jaws** (1975) **PG**: shark attacks and kills a boy on a raft
- *Come drink with me* (1966) (not rated in the US, from PG to 16+ in other countries): a boy-monk is killed via poisoned needle shot to his eye
- *Once upon a time in the West* (1968) **PG-13**: a boy is killed with his whole family
- *Don't look now* (1960) **R**: starts with a child drowning in a pond
- *Canyon passage* (1946) **TV-PG**: both mother and child killed on-screen by Indians
- *Frankenstein* (1931) **TV-PG**: the Monster throws a girl into a lake where she drowns.
- *Country Doctor* (1909) has a child dying of a mysterious illness

So while indeed it happens quite rarely it did happen before 1980.

The rating is a bit hard to find for older movies, and it is hard to say that a child's death has caused an increased rating. In the case of really old ones like *Frankenstein* or *Canyon Passage*, the answer would be "no", as they are close to the PG rating. *Don't look now* is famous for a [very realistic sex scene](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3132952/So-did-didn-t-Julie-Christie-reveals-notorious-sex-scene-four-decades-Don-t-Look-Now.html) which caused quite a scandal, the death of the girl probably had little to do with it. *Assault...* and *Cross...* are generally brutal and graphic, hence the rating, while *Come drink...* is a wuxia movie, so while it is brutal with many deaths, it did not get overly high restriction in most countries.

Comment: as you said rare -- did it affect rating just as using more than a quota of curse words did?

Comment: @releseabe possibly, but remember that there are different classification in different countries. The *Assault...* is rater R in USA but 13+ in Canada for example

Answer (score 0):

I add a number of films I have seen where one or more children die.

The Village of the Damned (1995)

The Adventures of Huck Finn (1993)

Robocop 2 (1990)

Pet Cemetary (1989)

Children of the Corn (1984)

The Final conflict (1981)

Zulu Dawn (1979)

Damien: Omen II (1978)

What the Peeper Saw (1972)

Ulzana's Raid (1972)

Soldier Blue (1970)

Sudden Terror/Eyewitness (1970)

The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly (1966)

Tower of London (1962) [https://moviechat.org/tt0056606/Tower-of-London/58c724625ec57f0478ed7087/The-Child-Princes-Possible-Spoilers?reply=5df2aa640f49722942728325&animate=false[1]](https://moviechat.org/tt0056606/Tower-of-London/58c724625ec57f0478ed7087/The-Child-Princes-Possible-Spoilers?reply=5df2aa640f49722942728325&animate=false%5B1%5D)

The Innocents (1961)

The Village of the damned (1960)

The Giant Gehemoth (1959) [https://moviechat.org/tt0052611/The-Giant-Behemoth/58c706b84e1cf308b937c223/A-Grim-Aspect-of-this-Film?reply=5df2aa2d0f49722942728320&animate=false[2]](https://moviechat.org/tt0052611/The-Giant-Behemoth/58c706b84e1cf308b937c223/A-Grim-Aspect-of-this-Film?reply=5df2aa2d0f49722942728320&animate=false%5B2%5D)

The Oregon Trail (1959): [https://moviechat.org/tt0053145/The-Oregon-Trail/58c723465ec57f0478ec8e10/Unusually-violent-for-its-time[3]](https://moviechat.org/tt0053145/The-Oregon-Trail/58c723465ec57f0478ec8e10/Unusually-violent-for-its-time%5B3%5D)

The Bad Seed (1956)

The Yellow Tomahawk (1954)

Westward the Women (1951)

Tomahawk (1951)

Rocky Mountain (1950)

Tower of London (1939)

The Charg eo fthe  Light Brigade (1936)

End of the Trail: (1932)

Frankenstein (1931)

It is quite possible there is at least one film where a child is seen dying onscreen for each of the more than 120 years that movies have been made.

Comment: my question is whether it was rarer at one point. i definitely recall being surprised at the scene when i saw it: the kid was sort of being "animated" by the Blob, almost as if the monster was displaying a sadistic sense of humor. the kid in Frankenstein i am not sure we see dead -- i think it was implied.

Comment: @relesabe  In Fankenstein 1931 The monster is seen playing with the little girl by a pond, and in a later scene the girl's father carries her lifeless body into the village and forms a lynch mob to avenge her.